# HDP Decommissioning a node

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I was following the HDP guide to decommission a node in a HDP cluster.

In theory, if the node I want to decommission is running both a DataNode and NodeManager, once I follow the steps in http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_Sys_Admin_Guides/content/ref-a179736c-eb7c-4dda-b3b4-6f3a778bd8c8.1.html to decommission the DataNode then the NodeManager is decommissioned by default? since at the end of this step it says to shut down this node without saying anything more about the NodeManager.

Comment: the steps given in the link will decompose only datanode. Nodemanager will not be decommissioned by default -> http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_Sys_Admin_Guides/content/ref-5981b2ae-bdc1-4eeb-8d01-fa2c088edf83.1.html

Comment: yes I understand that, but in theory what happens if the NodeManager and DataNode are on the same node(that will shut down according to the final steps in my link above)?

Comment: I dont think its mandatory to decommission the nodemanager. if we shutdown the node after decommissioning datanode, the nodemanager service will get stopped and will not give any job to that node